# Replacing text with sed (without interpreting it as regex)

Tags: sed

I am simply trying to replace text in bash, but having a hard time doing so. Other posts from years ago seem to result in an extremely complicated process, but I was hoping to get some easier and simpler assistance.

Here's the text that I have:

```
Here is a random sentence that contains [ABC-123](https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1) somewhere in the middle of it.
```

Here's what I'm trying to replace in the above text:

```
➜  ~ echo $replace_string
[ABC-123](https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1)
```

I am trying to replace it with this:

```
➜  ~ echo $replace_with
<https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1|[ABC-123]>
```

I am ultimately trying to convert Markdown interpreted by GitHub into Markdown that is interpreted by Slack (for whatever reason have their own way of doing this).

I have tried using `sed`, but this just does work because it keeps trying to interpret the replace strings as regex

```
➜  ~ echo $contents
Here is a random sentence that contains [ABC-123](https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1) somewhere in the middle of it.
➜  ~ echo $replace_string
[ABC-123](https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1)
➜  ~ echo $replace_with
<https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1|[ABC-123]>
➜  ~ echo $contents | sed "s/$replace_string/$replace_with/g"
sed: 1: "s/[ABC-123](https://app ...": RE error: invalid character range
```

Is there just a simple way to turn off regex interpretation in `sed` or another equivalent way using another utility? Other than modifying the text itself via `sed`, I am hoping to be able to use variables which hold the text, since the text will vary in many cases.

Comment: Use `awk` instead of sed. Awk has an `index(str)` function to find substrings, `length()` to measure the number of chars, and `substr()` to cut out and concatenate strings. None of those recognise any REs or special characters, so no issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need then to escape those special characters and then it works:

```
sed 's@\[ABC-123](https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1)@<https://app.website.com/random/path/here?query=1|\[ABC-123]>@'
```

I used '@' as the syntax delimiter so that one doesn't need to escape every single '/' too.

Comment: Even _less_ escaping is necessary if you don't use `-r` (which enables extended regular expressions). Without `-r`, you would not have to escape `(`, `)`,  `|`, or `?` since you're dealing with basic regular expressions. Also note that `&`, if it occurs, must be escaped in the replacement text, as well as `\n` for any number `n` in both pattern and replacement.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you, I modified it. Very often I need to use capture groups, + and ?, so it has become a habit for me to start with -r.

Comment: Capture groups are written `\(...\)` in basic regular expressions and `+` and `?` are just syntactic sugar for `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}`. Note too that in a future POSIX standard, the option to enable extended regular expressions in `sed` will most probably be `-E` rather than the GNU option `-r`.  GNU `sed` understands both options.

Comment: Unfortunately, the text varies and so I was hoping to use a variable when replacing the text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use `pandoc` with following filter https://github.com/omarish/pandoc-md-to-slack